# Determining files in a directory using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am replacing the Distribution section in my many metadata records to include optional references to other non-xml files.  Each xml metadata record is in a separate folder, and in each such folder there may or may not be a PDF document and perhaps an Excel file.  These three files have independent names.  I basically need a directory list, which I can access and manipulate.

The following is a subset of what I have been attempting, although as it stands it does compile using Kernow-Saxon 9PE.  The first part seems to construct the correct path to the desired subdirectory, albeit with a “file:/” prefix.
My problems are:

1. Do I need to go to the effort I am making to determine the path?  (It seems “un-xsl-ish”).  Kernow easily finds the metadata.xml file in each subdirectory.
2. I don’t think I have the “for-each” statement correct.  In versions where it does execute, I temporarily limit “select=*.*” as “select=*.xml” (and it only does the metadata.xml files).
3. Without the override mentioned, I get “Variable filename has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)”

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="gmd:distributionInfo" >
    <gmd:distributionInfo>
        <gmd:distributorTransferOptions>
            <!-- construct path to directory containing xml metadata and non-xml files -->
           <xsl:variable name="pathParts" select="tokenize(base-uri(),'/') " />
            <!-- remove filename.extension, reconstruct path -->
            <xsl:variable name="directory" select="string-join((remove($pathParts,count($pathParts))),'/')" />
            <gmd:dir>
                <gco:CharacterString>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "$directory" />
                </gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:dir>
            <!-- loop thru all files to obtain filenames -->
            <xsl:for-each select="for $filename in collection(concat($directory, select='*.*')) return $filename " >
                <!-- temporary? override to enable xslt compilation -->
                <xsl:variable name="filename" select= "base-uri()" />
                <gmd:name>
                    <gco:CharacterString>
                        <xsl:value-of select= "$filename" />
                    </gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:name>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </gmd:distributorTransferOptions>
    </gmd:distributionInfo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

A dummy metadata record would as attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
    <gmd:fileIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString>56400C76-E5E3-44D7-904C-90B97858F7CE</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
    </gmd:identificationInfo>
    <gmd:distributionInfo>
        <gmd:MD_Distribution>
        </gmd:MD_Distribution>
    </gmd:distributionInfo>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. Please show the desired output and the actual output and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the defined `$filename` outside of your xpath `for $i in x` statement.

Try making the following changes to your code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $filename in collection(concat($directory, select='*.*')) return $filename " >
            <gmd:name>
                <gco:CharacterString>
                    <xsl:value-of select= "base-uri(.)" />
                </gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:name>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The select statement in the for-each should return a document node for each item in your collection, `base-uri(.)` will give you the filename for each document node.

Also if you only have xml files in your collection I would use `select='*.xml'` because if there were other files in your directory that statement would fail.